# add field with date field

Tags: entities

I have created new field for my content type "Flag", its list type field

possible values of it is

```
-Draft 
-Sent 
-Approved 
-Rejected
```

now for this field new table is created,now i want to store date here,what i exactly want is like:

```
-Draft on date DD/MM/YYYY (the date of the creation of the project)
-Sent on date DD/MM/YYYY
-Approved on date DD/MM/YYYY
-Rejected on date DD/MM/YYYY
```

now how to achieve it.

**am using drupal 7**

Answer (score 2):

Use [Field Collections](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) and add two fields to field collection and enable field collection field on your content type... Or Create two fields Flag and Flag date...

- Flag
- Flag Date

OR

You can use revisions to track these changes in Drupal. When ever you change above field make content as a new revision so that you can track dates too...

OR

Create a few more date fields, each for possible values to track the dates... use form api [#states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states) property to hide display fields based on selection of flag value..

- Flag
- Draft Date
- Sent Date
- Approved Date
- Rejected Date

Comment: oh yes i like the second suggestion,but how to maintain it,means whenever article flag changed to any other value need to add it not update it then and then only i will get date for all flags

Comment: Updated my answer :-)

Comment: Create a few more date fields, each for possible values to track the dates. means?

Comment: and i can not use revisions, because we can not check which fields updated in that action

Comment: Check Updated answer ..

Comment: yeah i got that we need different fields but when to update it that how to controll?